# How to find which are the neighboring clusters of each cluster on a scatterplot?

Tags: cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, nearest-neighbor, voronoi

So, I run some clustering algorithm to find clusters. Now i want to find the clusters that are neighbours. I tried using voronoi diagram to pull regions that share ridges but it doesn't work.

So in this image, I want cluster 0 to have cluster 1,3,4,5,6. all clusters that share borders basically. how do i do this? thanks [I clustered using agglomerative clustering, plotted voronoi using cluster centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5KUd.png)

Comment: I am also interested in this problem. I also would like to find an easy way to select the region(s) of interest and save the points in the voronoi region in an array.